# AWS Athena [Presto] How to receive data from the past 7 days only?

Tags: sql, date, presto

I've gone through multiple similar threads but still can't get this to work for some reason.  I have this query that is currently pulling all data from stage_date in January, but I want to be able to get the data from only the past week (7 days).  When I've done some of the other answers for questions similar to this I get an error like > cannot be applied to varchar, date  or something along those lines. (When I put the > currentdate formula in my query)

```
    select reason_code, service_category, stage_date,
    case when reason_code LIKE 'UAR' 
    then 'Unauthorized Return'       
    else 'FALSE'
    end as "reason_long",
    
    case when service_category like 'CRED'
    then 'Credit Approved'
    else 'FALSE'
    end as "service_long"
    from "table.name"
    where
    stage_date like '01%'
    order by customer_name,
    stage,
    reason_code
```

Comment: what the data type of stage_date? And please show your try with WHERE and current date

Answer (score 0):

If stage_date  is of type string, cast it to date:

```
WHERE date(stage_date) >= current_date() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```